# What is necessary to memory allocation be deterministic on linux?

Tags: c, ubuntu, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-address

So, I'm trying to do a little bot to automatize some boring tasks in a single player game. I'm a linux user so I don't have those game trainers that runs on windows, and besides that I want to learn more about memory allocation xD.

With that in mind, I want to know what can make the process of memory allocation non-deterministic. On my firsts tests I used this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/**
 * main - uses strdup to create a new string, loops forever-ever
 *
 * Return: EXIT_FAILURE if malloc failed. Other never returns
 */
int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    unsigned long int i;

    s = strdup("Holberton");
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't allocate mem with malloc\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    i = 0;
    while (s)
    {
        printf("[%lu] %s (%p)\n", i, s, (void *)s);
        sleep(1);
        i++;
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This code was compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror loop.c -o loop
```

Which returns something like that:

```
[0] Holberton (0x5619c31ca260)
[1] Holberton (0x5619c31ca260)
[2] Holberton (0x5619c31ca260)
[3] Holberton (0x5619c31ca260)
[4] Holberton (0x5619c31ca260)
```

So every time I run this code the address printed changes, then I searched a little bit and discovered that most recent linux distro has ASLR activated by default for security, avoiding some exploits with overflow. When I deactivated the ASLR this code started to print always the same address. Ok, so ASLR is one of the reasons. So I started to test with the game (now using [scanmen](https://github.com/scanmem/scanmem) to search the address), and every time that I restart the game all address are different from the last run.

PS: The address founded in both cases (my C code and on the game) are in the heap.
PS2: It's possible to read more about the C code on [this git](https://github.com/holbertonschool/Hack-The-Virtual-Memory/blob/master/00.%20C%20strings%20%26%20the%20proc%20filesystem/loop.c).

I'd like to know why this happens? It's because the game uses dynamic allocation (like malloc), if so there is any method to force determinism? If it's because dynamic allocation the address shouldn't be on stack? Why it's always on heap?

Also what is the pointer scan? I tried to search about and all I found is some guys using game trainers on windows, I would like to know how it works, and why the pointer is deterministic.

Comment: You can try to allocate an array of the subject. Then use each cell of the array for determinism.

Comment: Because then the cells are pre-determined and you would know where to place the instance of a subject. I think the non determinism comes from the fact that system allocates any available space in the heap.

Comment: But if the system allocates any available space in the heap, why my variable (in the C code), is always on the same address (after disable ASLR)?

Comment: Computers are deterministic. Every time you run the same sequence of mallocs, you'll get the same pointers. Unless malloc randomization is in effect.

Comment: Yor loop doesn't change `s`. So it will always be the same pointer address. What did you expect?

Comment: Since the code doesn't change I should be always the same pointer address, why in the compiled code this doesn't happens also?

Comment: As per my search. ASLR places different sections of the program in different mem locations to avoid attackers from using any memory hack. It must mean that heap will get a random memory location and the malloc allocation might not be random. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah ASLR does that, thatsy my loop was changing the memory address on every run, but when I disable the ASLR the loop became deterministic but the compiled code of the game doesn't. So there is another reason for the address always change on the game.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Computers are not deterministic. OP has presented a simple example in this question, but we do not know what the rest of their software is. The simple example runs in an environment that is artificially constructed to be deterministic, but this is not true for programs in general. A program with multiple threads will have those threads scheduled in conjunction with timers. Those timers are affected by the real world and will not trigger at the some point in every program execution. The speed at which the processor runs will be affected by heat and cold.…

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: One thread that performs the same sequence of `malloc` calls may see different results because other threads have intervened. A game program may call upon random number routines that use hardware features such as random numbers from thermal noise (built into Intel processors). Communications from the outside world may arrive at varying times (key strokes, disk responses, network packets).

Comment: @EricPostpischil so u are saying that probably the code of the game is changing the memory address because the allocation is performed in different sequences and times each run, and because of that even malloc being deterministic external stuffs are changing the result?

Comment: @LucasAraújo: We would need to know more about your game. Is it multithreaded? Does it communicate with external things, such as a network server? Does it use timers? What random number services does it use?

Comment: @EricPostpischil it probably doesn't communicate with a network server, but I don't have the others information, I belive that it's multithreaded but can't be sure. How can I start to analyze this points? Using the command file from linux I recieve that (IDK if this is a useful information):
 'ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0f2ee83e15b5f3b1f59fce207243a5eef584b718, stripped'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202108/discussion-between-lucas-araujo-and-eric-postpischil).